# A non trivial system verifying some statements;

Tags: vector-spaces

For every abelian group $(V,\oplus)$  and an unitary field $\left( {{\Bbb F},{\text{ }} + ,{\text{  }}{\text{.}}} \right)$ acting on $(V,\oplus)$ by the external operation $\odot$ .

Question  : Is there a non trivial system such that  :

1. $\forall x, y \in V, \  \ $  $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{F}, \  \ $ $\alpha \odot \left( x \oplus y \right) = \left(\alpha \odot x \right)\oplus\left( \alpha \odot y\right)$ .
2. $\forall x \in V, \  \ $  $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}, \  \ $ $\left( \alpha + \beta \right) \odot x =  \left(\alpha \odot x \right)\oplus\left( \beta \odot x\right)$ .
3. $\forall x \in V, \  \ $  $\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}, \  \ \alpha \odot \left( \beta \odot x \right) = \left( \alpha\cdot \beta \right) \odot x$ .
4. $\exists u \in V , \  \  u \ne {0_V} \Rightarrow {{\text{1}}_{\Bbb F}} \odot {\text{ }}u  \ne u $ .

   And if yes, is there a general theorem of a such system?

Comment: Does the operation $\alpha\cdot x=0$ count, or is that too trivial?

Comment: triviality here is about the whole system, Chris Culter, not only the possible values that it could take, null or whatever the value.

Comment: I can't tell if that was a "yes" or a "no"